# How to alter a class using a method based off user input within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Building a simple to-do list app to teach myself classes. Nearly everything works (so far, you can add items, view the list, and remove items). But, I can't seem to figure out how to implement a change item feature. This is supposed to change the name of an already created item, but the code I'm working on isn't doing it.

```
# counters for telling if a slot is empty or not
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0

# overarching class for entire program
# outlines how a list item is structured
class Item():

    def __init__(self, thingToDo, dueDate, priority):
        self.thingToDo = thingToDo
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.priority = priority

    def thingChange(self):
        thingChange = input("What would you like to change it to? ")
        self.thingToDo = thingChange


def whatToChange():
    global whatToChange
    whatToChange = input("What in the item would you like to change (1. thing, 2. due date, 3. priority)?")
    if "1" in whatToChange:
        itemChange = input("What would you like to change it to? ")
        item1.thingToDo = itemChange
        printCurrentList()


# takes inputs to add an instance of to do item
def getItem():
    global thing
    thing = input("What do you want to do?")
    global time
    time = input("When do you need to do it by?")
    global importance
    importance = input("Priority (rate out of 5): ")

# each of these takes the inputs from getItem(), and puts them into the slots
def runItem1():
    getItem()
    global item1
    item1 = Item(thing, time, importance)

    print("1. You need to " + item1.thingToDo + " by " + item1.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item1.priority + "/5.")
    global a
    a = a + 1


def runItem2():
    getItem()
    global item2
    item2 = Item(thing, time, importance)

    print("2. You need to " + item2.thingToDo + " by " + item2.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item2.priority + "/5.")
    global b
    b = b + 1


def runItem3():
    getItem()
    global item3
    item3 = Item(thing, time, importance)

    print("3. You need to " + item1.thingToDo + " by " + item1.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item1.priority + "/5.")
    global c
    c = c + 1

def runItem4():
    getItem()
    global item4
    item4 = Item(thing, time, importance)

    print("4. You need to " + item4.thingToDo + " by " + item4.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item4.priority + "/5.")
    global d
    d = d + 1

def runItem5():
    getItem()
    global item5
    item5 = Item(thing, time, importance)

    print("5. You need to " + item5.thingToDo + " by " + item5.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item5.priority + "/5.")
    global e
    e = e + 1

# pretty self explanatory, prints out the current slots in a list-type format
def printCurrentList():
    if a > 0:
        print("1. You need to " + item1.thingToDo + " by " + item1.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item1.priority + "/5.")
    else: print("Slot 1 is empty.")

    if b > 0:
        print("2. You need to " + item2.thingToDo + " by " + item2.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item2.priority + "/5.")
    else:
        print("Slot 2 is empty.")

    if c > 0:
        print("3. You need to " + item1.thingToDo + " by " + item1.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item1.priority + "/5.")
    else:
        print("Slot 3 is empty.")

    if d > 0:
        print("4. You need to " + item4.thingToDo + " by " + item4.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item4.priority + "/5.")
    else:
        print("Slot 4 is empty.")

    if e > 0:
        print("5. You need to " + item5.thingToDo + " by " + item5.dueDate + ", and the priority is " + item5.priority + "/5.")
    else:
        print("Slot 5 is empty.")

# adds an item to the list, but first, checks to see if list slots are already used -- uses a,b,c,d,e
def add():
    printCurrentList()
    if a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0 and d > 0 and e > 0:
        print("You need to empty a slot before you add another item.")
        whichToRemove = input("Which slot would you like to remove?")
        if input == "1":
            print("What would you like to add in its place?")
            runItem1()
    else:
        slot = input("Which slot would you like to use?: ")
        if slot == "1":
            runItem1()
        elif slot == "2":
            runItem2()
        elif slot == "3":
            runItem3()
        elif slot == "4":
            runItem4()
        elif slot == "5":
            runItem5()
        else:
            print("Error. Please try again.")
            add()

# main loop of the program
def main():
    prompt = input("What do you want to do (add, remove, change, or view)?: ")
    if prompt == "add":
        add()
    elif prompt == "remove":
        printCurrentList()
        whichToRemove = input("Which one would you like to remove?: ")
        if whichToRemove == "1":
            print("Item 1, " + item1.thingToDo + ", has been removed.")
            global a
            a = 0
        elif whichToRemove == "2":
            print("Item 2, " + item2.thingToDo + ", has been removed.")
            global b
            b = 0
        elif whichToRemove == "3":
            print("Item 3, " + item3.thingToDo + ", has been removed.")
            global c
            c = 0
        elif whichToRemove == "4":
            print("Item 4, " + item4.thingToDo + ", has been removed.")
            global d
            d = 0
        elif whichToRemove == "5":
            print("Item 5, " + item5.thingToDo + ", has been removed.")
            global e
            e = 0
        printCurrentList()

    elif prompt == "view":
        print("Here is your current list: ")
        printCurrentList()

    elif prompt == "change":
        whichToChange = input("Which one would you like to change?: ")
        if "1" in whichToChange:
            oldItem = item1.thingToDo
            whatToChange()
            thingChange()
            print("Item 1, " + oldItem + ", has been changed to " + item1.thingToDo)
        elif "2" in whichToChange:
            print("Item 2, " + item2.thingToDo + ", has been changed to _____________.")
        elif "3" in whichToChange:
            print("Item 3, " + item3.thingToDo + ", has been changed to _____________.")
        elif "4" in whichToChange:
            print("Item 4, " + item4.thingToDo + ", has been changed to _____________.")
        elif "5" in whichToChange:
            print("Item 5, " + item5.thingToDo + ", has been changed to _____________.")
        printCurrentList()
    main()

main()
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: That's way too much code, you need to first debug yourself and figure out which part exactly is causing you problems. Also there's way too much `global` usage, that can't be good

Comment: `global whatToChange` means that the first time you call `whatToChange` it overwrites the reference to itself with user input.

Comment: Start by getting rid of all the globals, and define your functions to take arguments and return values instead. You should start to see some patterns that would let you write a single `runItem` function instead of five separate `runItemX` functions.

Comment: You'll want to use lots of lists and dicts instead of doing things like defining 5 separate (but similar) variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing procedural methods with object orientated methods. 
One of the principles of object orientated design is determining where the functions belong ... which functions belong to which class.
Once I had that sorted out for myself moving from thinking just procedurally to thinking in terms of objects became much easier for me.

I suggest creating a list [], or a dictionary {} to store your items.

Then print current list can be handled by

```
item_list = []
# ... create items and add to item_list using item_list.append(item)

for item in item_list: 
     print(item)
```

or

```
item_dictionary = {}
# create items and add to item_dictionary using item_dictionary[some_key] = item
for key in item_dictionary:
    item = item_dictionary[key]
```

Then add whatever functions you need for your item class and use methods to add/remove/edit those items in the list of the dictionary.

I'd also drop the globals as the commentators suggested. I don't use globals at all in the python code I write.